# Rails - How to fake PUT or DELETE request using XDomainRequest in IE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer, xdomainrequest, xdr

How can I fake a PUT or DELETE request using XDomainRequest in IE? Or do I need to use an iframe transport?

I'm trying to access a restful API that's setup for CORS.  It works in all other browsers but I can't figure out how to fake the PUT/DELETE actions in IE.  With `XDomainRequest`, [custom headers are not allowed](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx), so I can't add the `HTTP_X_HTTP_METHOD_OVERRIDE` header which supposedly tells Rails to recognize the `_method=put` parameter in the json data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution I could think of was to add two new member routes mapped to #update and #destroy:

```
resources :posts do
    member do
        post :revise, :action => :update
        post :annihilate, :action => :destroy
    end
end
```

which added these routes when you run 'rake routes':

```
    revise_post POST   /posts/:id/revise(.:format)     {:action=>"update", :controller=>"posts"}
annihilate_post POST   /posts/:id/annihilate(.:format) {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"posts"}
```

---

Note that I originally tried this:

```
resources :posts do
    member do
        post :update
        post :destroy
    end
end
```

hoping that it would create these routes:

```
 update_post POST   /posts/:id/update(.:format)  {:action=>"update", :controller=>"posts"}
destroy_post POST   /posts/:id/destroy(.:format) {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"posts"}
```

but instead it created:

```
POST   /posts/:id(.:format) {:action=>"update", :controller=>"posts"}
POST   /posts/:id(.:format) {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"posts"}
```

which look like they are overlapping and you could never get to posts#destroy.